# Calling a studio field ? Odoo V14

Tags: odoo, onchange, custom-fields

I would like to know if it's possible or not to call an Odoo studio field in a model like this ?

```py
class sale_order(models.Model):
   _inherit = "sale.order"
            
   @api.onchange('x_studio_first_field')
   def _onchange_firstfield(self):
       if self.x_studio_first_field:
           self.x_studio_second_field = self.x_studio_first_field
```

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the answer is what i've write in exemple. I tried it and it works !

```py
class sale_order(models.Model):
        _inherit = "sale.order"
            
        @api.onchange('x_studio_first_field')
        def _onchange_firstfield(self):
            if self.x_studio_first_field:
                self.x_studio_second_field = self.x_studio_first_field
```